# Can not find 'div' with specific 'class' with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

I recently started to apply Beautifulsoup in Python to learn some scrapping skills, However I have experienced some problems and can't figure them out. Here is my problem:

I'm trying to find some `'div'` in the website, when I inspected the site, I could see the specific class within div, however, when I tried to run the code, it return empty list, could anyone explain it why?

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url=urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/mediaviewer/rm3597327872')
soup=BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
div=soup.find_all('div',class_='pswp__zoom-wrap')
print(div)
```

Actually I've encountered this problem several places, and have been trying to figure it out, but still have no clue why!

Comment: The page is using JavaScript to load most of its content; the HTML returned from the initial request is pretty minimal. You're going to need something more akin to a headless browser that can execute javacript in order to scrape this page.

Comment: so chrome itself is not supporting such kind of scrapping, right? thx !

Comment: No, not quite. The problem is that BeautifulSoup just looks at the HTML that comes down from the server; it does not execute JS. On that page, most of the stuff you see when you inspect the site is being created by JS, not being served directly as HTML

Comment: thx i am using the phan and selenium driver and the problem seemed fixed, thx!

Comment: thx really helps a lot!! thx hamms!